# Equivalent of .show() - jQuery in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Anyone has any idea whats the equivalent of.show() of jquery in javascript?

I have tried using document.getElementById and add / remove class that I named "show" // "hide" but that doesn't work very well I might have wrong attributes in those classes I am not sure..

the show class is :

```css
.show{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

and the hide class is:

```css
.hide{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

I am pretty sure there is a better way of going so.

Comment: Note that if you want to use a class that has `display:none` you don't need those other attributes in the class.

Comment: Most of this answers are **outdated / incorrect.** See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643079/383904

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = 'block'; // show
document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = 'none'; // hide
```

Comment: Yea your works mattnull thanks very much this is exactly what i were looking for.

Comment: @Fresheyeball no it isn't truly identical at all. Not all elements are `display: block;`. There's inline, inline-block, table, table-cell, list-item, and so on so on. jQuery show does not make these `display: block`.

Comment: Yes, jQuery takes into account what you are showing... span would be style.display = 'inline' ... etc ... this isn't an equivalent

Answer (score 7):

jQuery takes into account what the value of `display` was before hiding. When you fire `show()`, it returns it back to what that value was. And so, it's NOT just simply setting the element's `display` property to `block` and `none`.

so basically:

```
function hide(){
    //get previous display value
    //store it in an internal cache. jQuery has an internal data storage
    //hide element
}

function show(){
    //get previous display value for that element
    //apply to element to show it
}
```

---

> [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
>
> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("MyId").className='show'`
`document.getElementById("MyId").className='hide'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using document.getElementsByClassName since you are using .show and .hide.  These are classes and you are trying to targer by Id.  Disclaimer: you may want to double check on old browsers' support for that.

Answer (score 0):

Before jQuery, I used the following method to show/hide an element:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.toggleDisplay = function(on_or_off, display_type) {
    if (typeof(tddisptype) == "undefined") tddisptype = "block";
    var new_display;
    if (typeof(on_or_off) != "boolean") {
        if (this.style.display == "none") new_display = display_type;
        else new_display = "none";
    } else {
        if (on_or_off) new_display = display_type;
        else new_display = "none";
    }
    this.style.display = new_display;
}​
```

This adds a toggleDisplay() function to all elements; e.g., ones that you could get via document.getElementById().  You can either pass it `true` or `false` as a parameter to show or hide the element, or if you don't pass it a parameter, it will try to figure out whether to show or hide the element.  The second argument specifies the type of display associated with the "on" state; above, it defaults to `block`.